# jquery eventhandler and documentready: handler binds too late

Tags: jquery, forms, handler, domdocument

So I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();//do not submit the form
      //go to a specific place
   });
});
```

Now unfortunately, my page needs to load quite a bit of data, so it takes a bit until it's ready. The button is inside a form.

If the page hasn't fully loaded, and the user clicks the button, I DO actually get the default event (submit the form) executed...which I do not want

In the workflow we have it's unlikely that that button be pressed that quickly - but the fact that it could annoys me. Any idea what could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disable the button by default and after loading the page enable the button

Answer (score 0):

Disable the form's submit action if you intend to handle the submit with ajax instead.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to have a loading indicator or a spinner on click of the button and disable it as soon as it is clicked, so that the user knows he is expecting something rather than just double clicking it.